# Concatenate 'table name + id', then use that variable to drop and create a new table name in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm in the process of creating partitioned tables, so I need to create one table per cost center using an input table that may have one or more rows of cost center data.  The input table has a column named `'cost_center'`.  I'm using Postgresql 9.5.

To concatenate the table name, I wrote the following:

```
select cost_cent, 
concat('a_save_tbl_', cost_center) hold_tbl_name from a_input_tbl 
limit 1;
```

This command returns `'a_save_tbl_AA'` which is the right table name.  Then I tried variations of:

```
query1 := format('drop if exists %I, hold_tbl_name);
```

No success.  I can't find the right code to drop, create and populate the new tables.  I read a lot of posting and documentation but, everything returns syntax errors.  I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
drop if exists %I
```

is syntactically wrong. It should be `drop table if exists %I`

Having said that, It is likely that your table `a_save_tbl_AA`  has been created normally without using double quotes.
The [format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function with `%I` treats the argument value as an SQL identifier, double-quoting it if necessary.

So, If you your `cost_center` is in uppercase(`'AA'`), it is better to convert and pass lowercase to substitute for `%I`. The below code works and may be useful for your actual requirement.

```
DO $$
 DECLARE 
  l_hold_tbl_name TEXT;
  query1 text ;
  query2 text ;
 BEGIN 
  SELECT Concat('a_save_tbl_', cost_center) 
  INTO   l_hold_tbl_name 
  FROM   a_input_tbl limit 1; 

  query1 := format('drop table if exists %I', lower(l_hold_tbl_name)); 
  query2 := format('create table  %I as select 2 as id',lower(l_hold_tbl_name)); 
  EXECUTE query1; 
  EXECUTE query2; 
END $$;
```

See [**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=7ee2500e2c0d6e2024ae277d97da6dc7) to see how things works with quotes.

Comment: Thank you, Kaushik!  Your answer was so helpful.

Comment: @giltdsur : you're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, please consider accepting it so that it'll also help others.

Comment: I also wanted to display the costcenter table on the screen, so I added:                                                                              query3 := format('select * from %I', lower(hold_tbl_name));
execute query3;   It executed without errors but, it did not display the table.  I would appreciate your help.

Comment: @giltdsur : `DO` block can't return a query result. You have to run the select outside the block.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll give that a try.

Comment: Kaushik, with your assistance I was able to create a function that did the job for about 50 cost centers with many tables of various names; so, the only outstanding challenge is how to construct the 'select' statements for each cost center since I don't really know the table names programmatically once I exit the function.

Comment: @giltdsur : As I said, you should ask a new question in Stack over flow if you have further questions and not use comment section. This answers your original question. Consider accepting it. Post a new question with the problem you are now solving linking this question. Thanks